# Unnexpected output in js sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, output

guys I am trying to sort an array  but I have a little problem, the sorting starts but 
one of the elements is marked as undefined and I can't  figure out why. In general I am not sure whether I call the function the right way. Please help me! :)

that's the code:

```
<p>JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me First!</button>

<div id="demoto0">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto1">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto2">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto3">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto4">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto5">This is gonna be changed </div>
<p> ---------------------------------------- </p>
<div id="demoto+0">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto+1">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto+2">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto+3">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto+4">This is gonna be changed </div>
<div id="demoto+5">This is gonna be changed </div>
<p id="flag"> false </p>
<script>
var arr = [1,2300, 94000, 34, 280, 294];
function selectionsort(cont){
    var ns = cont.ns;
    var n = cont.length;

    var n = arr.length;
    //var n = 6;
    for(var i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
    {
        var index = i; // markirame na4alna strelka ^
        for(var j=i+1; j<n; ++j)
        {
            // markirame sys strelki vseki element
            if(arr[index] > arr[j])
            {
                index = j;  
            }
        } 
        if(i != index)
        {
            var temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[index];
            arr[index] = temp;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("flag").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";

}

function myFunction() { 
    //var arr = [1,2300, 94000, 34, 280, 294];
    document.getElementById("demoto1").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    document.getElementById("demoto0").innerHTML = arr[0];
    document.getElementById("demoto1").innerHTML = arr[1];
    document.getElementById("demoto2").innerHTML = arr[2];
    document.getElementById("demoto3").innerHTML = arr[3];
    document.getElementById("demoto4").innerHTML = arr[4];
    document.getElementById("demoto5").innerHTML = arr[5];

    //arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
    selectionsort(arr);

    document.getElementById("demoto+0").innerHTML = arr[0];
    document.getElementById("demoto+1").innerHTML = arr[1];
    document.getElementById("demoto+2").innerHTML = arr[2];
    document.getElementById("demoto+3").innerHTML = arr[3];
    document.getElementById("demoto+4").innerHTML = arr[4];
    document.getElementById("demoto+5").innerHTML = arr[5]; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Note that there's a standard sort function in JS, you don't have to implement your own.

Comment: I don't want to use the standart sort function well I expect to see the elements sorted, but instead I see this:       1
2300
94000
34
280
294
----------------------------------------

1
2300
94000
undefined
34
294
Hello JavaScript!

Comment: The main problem is in your loop that uses `j` - Instead of making `index = j;` you need to get the two values of the array at `index` and `j`, and swap them around (using a temp variable). I've posted an answer with the updated function that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed it for you, just changed the selectionsort function a little. You need to use a temprary variable to switch the values round in the section iteration (using `j`) as well as right at the end.
This worked fine for me:

```
function selectionsort(cont){
var temp;
var n = cont.length;

for(var i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
{
    var index = i; // markirame na4alna strelka ^
    for(var j=i+1; j<n; ++j)
    {
        // markirame sys strelki vseki element
        if(cont[index] > cont[j])
        {
            temp = cont[j];
            cont[j] = cont[index];
            cont[index] = temp; 
        }
    } 
    if(i != index)
    {
        temp = cont[j];
        cont[j] = cont[index];
        cont[index] = temp;
    }
}

document.getElementById("flag").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";

}
```

I uplaoded a JSFiddle of it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yJVLZ/2/